# codeigniter routes

Tags: codeigniter

How to redirect controllers if they not match pattern.

For example I have follow controllers about_us, contacts, find_us. How to do so If the request method is not in that selection to be redirected to other controller ?

Answer (score 1):

For some reason it's not in the documentation for URI Routing in the User Guide. If you are using CI2, inside of your routes.php file you can use "404_override". It is one of the reserved routes.

$route['404_override'] = "error";

So when a user comes to a controller that is not one you have created or not something inside your routes.php file, it throws them into the "error" controller. Obviously you would have to make a controller called "error"

Answer (score -1):

Read about [routing](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html).